# Нужна ли запятая при обособлении несогласованного определения?

Tags: пунктуация

Люди добрые, нужна ли запятая в этом предложении?

...предлагать на выбор проектировщику различные варианты насосов и методов оптимизации их работы (,) с рассчитанными для них характеристиками...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не нужна. В технических текстах редко используются пояснительные обороты, пунктуация проста - по правилам.

**Обновление**

Несогласованные определения не всегда обосабливаются(шла девочка в красном платьице - нет причин обособления). А здесь" предлагать варианты насосов с  рассчитанными для них характеристиками..." - никакого особого выделения нет.

Хотя здесь структура предложения затемнена тем, что несогласованное определение отстоит далеко от главного слова,запятая возможна. Но я бы лучше предложение перестроила:предлагать на выбор проектировщику различные варианты насосов  с характеристиками,рассчитанными для  различных методов оптимизации их работы

Comment: А не является ли здесь "с рассчитанными для них характеристиками" несогласованным определением?

Comment: Хотя здесь структура предложения затемнена тем, что несогласованное определение отстоит далеко от главного слова,запятая возможна. Но я бы лучше предложение перестроила:предлагать на выбор проектировщику различные варианты насосов  с характеристиками,рассчитанными для  различных методов оптимизации их работы